# Is every closed Sasakian 3-manifold a circle bundle on a Riemann surface?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, 3-manifolds, fibre-bundles

It suffices to say that all circle bundles on compact Riemann surfaces admit the structure of a closed Sasakian 3-manifold. The question is, the converse of this statement and/or what are the sufficient conditions on a Sasakian 3-manifold that ensure it will be such a circle bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete topological classification is due to Geiges, and can be found in [this 2001 paper by Guilfoyle](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0102015v1.pdf). (the first Theorem in the paper).

Comment: @BenSmith: With the caveat that these manifolds are not necessarily circle bundles, they are Seifert fiber spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, but it is true up to deformations and is essentially due to Belgun. See Section 10.1 of the my book Sasakian Geometry, C.P. Boyer and K. Galicki.